# How to insert new item in the system menu

Tags: java, macos, swt

I want to add a new item to the program menu, f.e.

```
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(Display.getCurrent().getSystemMenu(), SWT.PUSH);
menuItem.setText("Check for updates");
```

It works perfect but now my new item is the last one in the menu.
Is it possible to change the order of the items so I can have for example the about item, the preferences item and then my update item as the third one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the version of the `MenuItem` constructor with an index value:

```
Menu sysMenu = display.getSystemMenu();

MenuItem item = new MenuItem(sysMenu, SWT.PUSH, 3);
item.setText("Check for updates");
```

The index '3' puts to menu item immediately after 'Preferences'